# How to view all installed packages in terminal (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, apt

Need to view all the packages installed on my system through terminal.
I am using ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Have you tried googling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# dpkg -l
```

From dpkg manual:

> dpkg-query actions
>                 See dpkg-query(1) for more information about the following actions.
>
> ```
>           -l, --list package-name-pattern...
>               List packages matching given pattern.
>           -s, --status package-name...
>               Report status of specified package.
>           -L, --listfiles package-name...
>               List files installed to your system from package-name.
>           -S, --search filename-search-pattern...
>               Search for a filename from installed packages.
>           -p, --print-avail package-name...
>               Display details about package-name, as found in
>               /var/lib/dpkg/available. Users of APT-based frontends
>               should use apt-cache show package-name instead.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To list packages installed only by you:

```
gunzip -c /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | grep 'apt-get install' | cut -f4- -d" " | tr ' ' $'\n' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** In order to view all installed packages in linux Ubuntu, run on terminal `apt --installed list`,

Use apt flags and would be able to see available upgrades to some packages ( `--upgradeable` ) / current installed packages ( `--installed` ) / all available versions ( `--all-versions` ).

From **Documentation**:

```
DESCRIPTION
       apt provides a high-level commandline interface for the package management system. 
       It is intended as an end user interface and enables some options better suited for interactive usage by
       default compared to more specialized APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8).

       Much like apt itself, its manpage is intended as an end user interface and as such only mentions the most 
      used commands and options partly to not duplicate information in multiple places and
       partly to avoid overwhelming readers with a cornucopia of options and details.
```

the `list` flag offers 3 options:

```
list (work-in-progress)
           list is somewhat similar to dpkg-query --list in that it can display a 
           list of packages satisfying certain criteria. It supports glob(7) 
           patterns for matching package names as well as
           options to list installed (--installed), upgradeable (--upgradeable) or 
           all available (--all-versions) versions.
```

Answer (score 0):

command to list all installed packages

```
sudo apt list --installed
```

you can add 'grep' to find your service as below:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep <my_service_name>
```

Comment: If I use it with grep I get the following error: WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Answer (score -1):

I used the following  Three Cmd Syntaxes & tested them to List installed packages on My ubuntu Subsystem machine from VB6 Shell() function and 2 of them Worked fine:

1-  Syntax-#1:[ Worked ]

sudo apt list --installed

2-  Syntax-#2:[ Worked ]

sudo dpkg -l

Syntax-#3: [ Do not Worked .. for me ]

sudo dpkg -l | grep -i apache

And Here is MY VB6 - Code List:

> Private Sub Command1_Click()
>
> Dim Id3 As Variant  ' 1- Syntax-#1: Worked fine:
>         Id3 = Shell(App.Path & "\bash.exe | sudo apt list --installed", vbNormalFocus)
>
> ' 2- Syntax-#2: Worked Also:   '   Id3 = Shell(App.Path & "\bash.exe
>   | sudo dpkg -l", vbNormalFocus)
>
> ' 3- Syntax-#3: Does not show output ... Why .. Dont know now:   '
>   Id3 = Shell(App.Path & "\bash.exe | sudo dpkg -l | grep -i apache",
>   vbNormalFocus)    End Sub**